# Maven: adding all .proto files to the plugin

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers

I have a lot of `.proto` files and I am using `maven-antrun-plugin` to generate the necessary Java files. It works as long as I specifically write each and every `.proto` file, like this:

```
<plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>generate-sources</id>
           <phase>generate-sources</phase>
           <configuration>
             <tasks>
               <mkdir dir="target/src-gen"/>
               <exec executable="protoc">
                 <arg value="--java_out=target/src-gen"/>
                 <arg value="target/proto/Empty.proto"/>
                 <arg value="target/proto/ComponentState.proto"/>
               </exec>
             </tasks>
             <sourceRoot>target/src-gen</sourceRoot>
           </configuration>
           <goals>
             <goal>run</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
```

This already works fine.

However, now that I get more .proto files (around 30), I cannot use the above method, since I'd have to write it one by one, and I don't think this is the appropriate way of doing it.

Is there a shortcut for this? To say "compile all `.proto` files under this directory and its subdirectories." would be very nice.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet works for me.

```
<configuration>
    <target>
    ... 
        <path id="protobuf.input.filepaths.path">
            <fileset dir="${protobuf.input.directory}">
                <include name="**/*.proto"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
    ...
    </target>
</configuration>
```